# Format php datetime as "Wednesday, April 16, 2014 at 2:24 PM"

Tags: php, mysql

I have this this datetime stored in db:
2014-04-16 14:24:24

I'd like to format it to:
Wednesday, April 16, 2014 at 2:24 PM

with this script: 
date("l, F d, Y \a\t g:i A", strtotime($list['publish_time']))

But it comes out as: 
Wednesday, April 16, 2014 a  2:24 PM

It seems the "t" in "at" is not escaping properly. Am I doing anything wrong? Please help, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use single quotes:

```
date('l, F d, Y \a\t g:i A', strtotime($list['publish_time']))
```

`\t` in double-quotes (`date("\t")`) is first parsed as tab character, thus the actual letter is missing.